# String Format to Date

Tags: vb.net, oracle, date

on my Database I got a field "Date" which contains a date format.

```
2016-08-19 15:47:50
```

My question now is, what is the right String Format to check wheather my variable is lower or higher?

for example:

```
DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,
 0,
 New DateTime(y, currentMonth, currentDay))
.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

The toString is obviously wrong since I get a literal error.

Can somebody give me the right format?

Comment: What does formatting have to do with `datetime` comparisons? Unless it is a `string` I guess?

Comment: What type is your Database field? If it is `Date` you don´t have to bother with string at all. Additionally why do you save the date in your code as year, month and day as numeric values and not directly as a date?

Comment: Fixed it myself, thread can be closed

Solution:
`DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 0, New DateTime(y, currentMonth, currentDay)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

@AlexB. it's a string field

Comment: Don´t do that. Use dates and times as `DateTime` and not as strings...

Comment: you can easily compare 2 dates in yyyyMMdd format

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format to compare date;

```
to_date('2016-08-19 15:47:50','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```